# How do I count unique values in Excel but ignoring blank cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count unique (text) values in a column using this formula:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(L2:L20))
```

This works, but it also counts blank cells.

How can I modify this to ignore blank cells? I tried adding the `FILTER` function inside the `UNIQUE`, but didn't work. I'm using Office 365

Comment: Does `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(L2:L20))+(IF(COUNTIF(L2:L20,"")>0,-1,0))` work?

Comment: Cannot repro your issue.  And since you chose not to share the code you tried with Filter, nor a representative data sample, it will be difficult to ascertain your problem.  Please read Help for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then **edit your question** to provide more information.

Comment: Sample data would be helpful. My guess is that you tried `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(L2:L20,L2:L20<>"")))`, which returns 1 when L2:L20 are all blank. In that case, @p._phidot_'s formula, or a slightly shorter version: `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(L2:L20))-(COUNTIF(L2:L20,"")>0)` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(IF(B3:B13="",B3,B3:B13)))
```

[image]

### Method 2

However, this assumes first cell in 'input range' is not a blank itself.  Thus, recommend going with:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(B3:B13))-COUNTIF(B3:B13,"")+1
```

[image: Preferred soln]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(L2:L20,L2:L20<>"")))